# How can a static method provided by a component be shown in an UML component diagam?

Tags: uml

Components can have a provided interface which could be shown with the ball notation or a realize dependency to an `<<interface>>`. But what if the component provides a static method?

Given a component `MyComponent` that provides its functionality via a public static mehtod `operation, would the following be a correct UML representation?

```
+---------------------+                  +---------------------------+
|    <<component>>    |   <<realize>>    |          AClass           |
|     MyComponent     |----------------->|---------------------------|
|                     |                  |+operation()    <<static>> |
+---------------------+                  +---------------------------+
```

Or should `AClass` be marked with the `<<interface>>` stereotype even if it is not implemented as an interface in the programming language? There are languages without an interface construct after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every construct is governed by rules in UML. So you have quite a certain degree of freedom. Especially when modeling static programming languages (like you have in embedded systems with lots of C programming) you need to setup your own rules how to express things. So basically nothing is wrong with the way you showed it. You should simply describe this construct in the modeling rules for the domain where you intend to use this construct. Probably I would stereotype `AClass` as `<<interface>>` since the fact that you have some public method exposed counts more than the fact that it is realized as static.

Answer (score 0):

Component element is defined as an specialized class element in UML superstructure. You can use it as a standard class element. You can define all standard features (operations, attributes, receptions) and connect with associations as well. If uml tool you are using offers to display component as a stereotyped class (<>), you will see all defined features there.